# Is there a way to determine what IP or computer used a particular script?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Our problem is, we want to know what computer or IP used a particular script. We already know when was the script used, but the problem is, our login is somehow global, We all use SA logins. Is there a way in SQL server to check which IP used a particular script? or maybe what IP changed a table?

Comment: Your organization should change its practices now.  You have no traceability.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Yeah, thanks to this I think we need to use different login credentials.

Comment: Lock down SA - everyone uses their own Windows account with trusted connections.  If a service process needs data access, it should be run on its own service account and use a trusted connection too. Good luck with this.  Implementation of new policy will be worth it in the long run.